# Second half of our first century activities

Tags: phrases

Is it suitable to use this expression to mean, we are active and alive in the market for more than 50 years? 
" As we are in Second half of our first century activities "

Comment: You could but there are far clearer ways of expressing that idea.

Comment: If you really want to use the "first century activities" idea it would be better to say something like "as we enter our second half century of activity", "as we look forward to our second half century of activity" or "having completed our first half century of activity" The trouble with "first century" is that it sounds like an historical date. "The first century" sounds to most English speakers like a cricket score or the years 1 to 100 of the Common Era, that is the middle of the Roman Empire.

Comment: What's your idea about the following words : Semi centenary, Semi-centennial, to be used in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "first century activities" is potentially confusing since "first century" can refer to ancient times.  "Our first century **of** activities" could help to prevent that particular confusion.

Some businesses try to be clever in the way their time in business is expressed.  A sentence like the following might seem dull and mundane to the writers they hire:

> We have been in business for more than fifty years.

and you will often see that fact expressed something like:

> Acme Widgets are entering our sixth decade in the widgets sector.

or even like the following, which seems rather foolish:

> Acme Widgets is approaching our seventh decade in the widgets sector.